# How did Snape know how to find Harry?

Tags: harry-potter

In [Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Deathly_Hallows), Snape somehow knows where to find Harry, and by knowing so, places the Sword of Gryffindor for Harry to find. How does he find him?

Comment: its magic! yay for character limits

Comment: I know this was answered somewhere. I remember reading it, but I forgot why... I will whip out my 7th book.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Harry asked Hermione where they were after they disapparate. Hermione was poking in her beaded bag for the tent and Phineas Nigellus's portait heard her mention it.

It's revealed on page 386(of e-book version) when Harry looked into Snape's memories in the Pensieve.

From the book:

> "And now Snape stood again in the headmaster’s study as Phineas Nigellus came hurrying into his portrait.
>
> “Headmaster! They are camping in the Forest of Dean! The Mudblood – ”
>
> “Do not use that word!”
>
> “ – the Granger girl, then, mentioned the place as she opened her bag and I heard her!”
>
> “Good. Very good!” cried the portrait of Dumbledore behind the headmaster’s chair.
>
> “Now, Severus, the sword!”

Comment: 689 of which version?

Comment: From the book: "And now Snape stood again in the headmaster’s study as Phineas Nigellus came hurrying into his portrait. 
“Headmaster! They are camping in the Forest of Dean! The Mudblood – ” 
“Do not use that word!”  
“ – the Granger girl, then, mentioned the place as she opened her bag and I heard her!” 
“Good. Very good!” cried the portrait of Dumbledore behind the headmaster’s chair. “Now, Severus, the sword!”

Comment: @rems: Thanks! Updated the answer. :)

Comment: I thought Jo was adamantly against e-books.

Comment: The Pirates are everywhere :( So much for being called "a dying breed".

Comment: @MikeBrown Jo was adamantly against the terms she had to abide by with the ebooks, which is why she ended up releasing them through Pottermore. I agree that it wouldn't be fair to have the same terms for wildly popular books that are being re-released as for new, untested books.